# Redis EXECABORT Transaction discarded because of previous errors. (Redis::CommandError) Sidekiq rror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I am using sidekiq 3.4.2 and redis 3.0.3 for some long running jobs and after about two~four hours I get the following error:

> ERROR: heartbeat: EXECABORT Transaction discarded because of previous errors.
>
> EXECABORT Transaction discarded because of previous errors.
>   /home/deployer/apps/wripl-capture/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/pipeline.rb:79:in
>   `finish'
>   /home/deployer/apps/wripl-capture/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:149:in`
>   block in call_pipeline'
>   /home/deployer/apps/wripl-capture/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:279:in
>   `with_reconnect'
>   /home/deployer/apps/wripl-capture/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:147:in`
>   call_pipeline'
>   /home/deployer/apps/wripl-capture/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:2182:in
>   `block in multi'
>   /home/deployer/apps/wripl-capture/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:37:in`
>   block in synchronize'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize'

Everything is killed (no enqueued jobs ran) unless I restart sidekiq, which is not what I need to do.

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 7):

I'd guess your Redis instance is out of memory.

Comment: I think you are right but I don't know how. I'll dig into it.

Answer (score 6):

This can also happen due to empty `multi` command.

running `redis-cli monitor` I saw

```
1546789398.881549 [0 the-ip] "multi"
1546789398.881575 [0 the-ip] "exec"
```

Before executing multi, make sure that you have at least 1 command to execute on the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

`multi` block is suppressing the actual error message. Run your code without the `multi` block to see the original error message.

I tried to run the entire code in `mutli` block within a try/rescue block, it still didn't catch the exception.

Answer (score -1):

Whatever command you are running through your code, try to run same commands through redis-cli.

You may get the actual error.

In my case actual error was :

> HSET some_key some_field some_value
>
> (error) NOREPLICAS Not enough good slaves to write.